# Removing html tags with regex (Java)

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, replaceall

Say I've read html input into a string and then do:

```
    content = content.replaceAll("<[^>]*[^\\s>][^>]*>", "");
```

Right now, this removes all html tags except those that look like:

```
    <>
```

and

```
    < (any amount of white space) >
```

but I'd also like to include tags that contain non-printable characters to that list of exceptions.
Is there anyway I can modify the replaceAll regular experssion to accomplish that?  If so, how?  Thanks for any input/suggestions.

Comment: Consider this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 and then think twice about parsing HTML with regex

Comment: I wish there's was an autoclose option on SO for all questions containing "html" and "regex"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
<[^\\P{Graph}>]+>
```

`\\P{Graph}` is a character class that only contains whitespaces and control characters *(this is the negation of `\\p{Graph}`)*

Comment: This is close, but if I have a tag like <tab located here:\t>, it will be replaced.  I'd like the tag to remain there (since tab is not a printable character).

Comment: @WizDom: If I understand well your needs, you want to remain empty "tags" or tags that contain at least one non printable character (space, tab, newline..., control character)?

Comment: @WizDom: In this case you can simply use: `<[^\\P{Graph}>]+>`

Comment: one more question, if space IS a printable character, how can I adjust this?

Comment: @WizDom: in this case, the most handy is probably to use a character class substraction *(instead of a negation)*: `<[ \\p{Graph}-[>]]+>`